# Creating an outlook rule for mail OlderThan: [x] days?

Tags: email, outlook

I have outlook rules which categorise my email into different  Categories. 
I prefer to categorise rather than move to folders as somtimes certain emails can contain more than 1 category.

I would like to automatically delete email that is Categorised: News and and is older than 1 week

However, there does not seem to be a "Date Older than" rule in outlook so I cant create a rule to do this. You can get fairly close with a custom search folder but not quite (custom search can allow you to search by "Category" and "Date Received"  but not "Older than" so the best I can do is set the search to Categorised (Strangely the prebuilt search folder options allow for an "Older than" selection through an Old Mail search but I also need to apply Category=News to my search and have to therefore use custom search.

In summary, is there an easy way for me to delete emails Categorised: News and Older Than: 1 week  through a rule or custom search?

The best I can get is a search folder which finds emails Categorised: News and REceived:yesterday and then I just manually delete them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Older than xxx date is not available as a filtering condition in standard Outlook rules. You'll need to write a VBA macro. You can base it on information in this post: [Outlook checks e-mails only in specific time frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29085514/outlook-checks-e-mails-only-in-specific-time-frame)

Alternatively, you can use a 3rd party rules Outlook add-in to do this directly. Check this product: http://www.pergenex.com/auto-mate/

Answer (score 1):

In case using an alternative software application is an viable option for you: This rule is a standard feature in Mozilla Thunderbird.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is not supported in Outlook. You can, as mentioned above, create a macro that moves the emails from one folder to another and then run that macro automatically when the user launches Outlook. For more details, check the link below:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mFqUUlNxQaA